# How to add a user input with an output in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Right I'm trying to make a calculator type thing and have zero knowledge of javascript, I need two input fields and two output fields, the formula of the calculation will be:

> Input 1: 25000
>
> Input 2: 30000
>
> Output 1: 112500
>
> Output 2: 142500
>
> Output 1 = Input 1 * 4.5
>
> Output 2 = input 2 + output 1

I've tried and calculating Output 1 is alright but I come to issues when calculating output 2. Please help me before I tear my hair out.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: You said you have zero knowledge of javascript : 
This is what one can suggest you at this point: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: _but I come to issues when **calculating** output 2_ . Whats the problem with output2, its simple maths, isnt it?

Comment: What you have tried so far? You should post your erroneous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple HTML and Javascript, you can do it following:

**HTML:**

```
Input1 : <input type="text" id="input1" value="25000" />
Input2 : <input type="text" id="input2" value="30000" />
<button onClick="calculate();">Calculate</button>

Output1 : <input type="text" id="output1" />
Output2 : <input type="text" id="output2" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
function calculate(){
    var input1Value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    var input2Value = document.getElementById('input2').value;

    var output1 = parseInt(input1Value) * 4.5;
    document.getElementById('output1').value = output1;

     var output2 = parseInt(output1) + parseInt(input2Value);
    document.getElementById('output2').value = output2;    
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6vqd4vnq/)

Isn't it quite easy? Just three steps involved:

1. Create a method, call it on button click.
2. Get field values and perform required operation(s).
3. Set output values back to the fields.

You should start with learning from basics.

Comment: @Louis Down, Try this one with pure javascript.

Comment: Style your fields to your requirement.

Comment: That's done it! thanks Parkash, very helpful. I shall do some more research next time and try to develop my knowledge.

Comment: Welcome! Its good to start with basic javascript, then going upward toward jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I made an example on jsFiddle ([click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/8ww55be2/1/)). It's really simple math.
Just calculate the first output, store it in a variable or read it from the output field and use that again to calculate the second output.

---

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Input</legend>First input:
    <input type="text" id="txtFirstInput" />
    <br/>Second input:
    <input type="text" id="txtSecondInput" />
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnCalculate" value="Calculate" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Output</legend>First output:
    <p id="pFirstOutput"></p>Second output:
    <p id="pSecondOutput"></p>
</fieldset>
```

---

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnCalculate").click(function () {
        var firstInput = $("#txtFirstInput").val();
        var firstOutput = firstInput * 4.5;
        var secondInput = $("#txtSecondInput").val();
        var secondOutput = parseInt(firstOutput) + parseInt(secondInput);
        $("#pFirstOutput").html(firstOutput);
        $("#pSecondOutput").html(secondOutput);
    });
});
```

---

**Javascript**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("btnCalculateJS").addEventListener("click", function() {
                var firstInput = document.getElementById("txtFirstInput").value;
        var firstOutput = firstInput * 4.5;
        var secondInput = document.getElementById("txtSecondInput").value;
        var secondOutput = parseInt(firstOutput) + parseInt(secondInput);
        document.getElementById("pFirstOutput").innerHTML = firstOutput;
        document.getElementById("pSecondOutput").innerHTML = secondOutput;
    }, false);
}, false);
```

Just keep in mind that JS does need to know that you are working with numbers.
Therefor in my example, I am using the 'parseInt()' function, which specifies the type.

Is this what you wanted?
Or did you want it to be with pure JS and not jQuery?

Comment: Hi Jorrex, that's exactly what I needed only I think I need it to be pure JS.

Comment: I changed my fiddle ;) now it has both jQuery and JS methods.

Answer (score 0):

This work and for decimal values.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script languages="javascript">
            function calculate() {
                var in_1 = document.getElementById('input_1');
                var in_2 = document.getElementById('input_2');
                var out_1 = document.getElementById('output_1');
                var out_2 = document.getElementById('output_2');

                var res_1 = Number(in_1.value) * 4.5;
                var res_2 = Number(in_2.value) + res_1;

                out_1.value = res_1;
                out_2.value = res_2;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Input 1:</label><input id="input_1"/>
        <label>Input 2:</label><input id="input_2"/>
        <button onClick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
        <hr/>
        <label>Output 1:</label><input id="output_1"/>
        <label>Output 2:</label><input id="output_2"/>
    </body>
</html>
```